# How to read an input from a barcode scanner and display into a TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

First barcode content will be: 1|**123456**|ABC

Second barcode content will be: 2|**123456789542**|ABCDSE

I just want to retrieve the bold part.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub TextScanPartNo_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextScanPartNo.KeyPress
    TextVendorID.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
    If Me.TextVendorID.Focused = False Then
        TextVendorID.Focus()
        TextVendorID.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString     
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you familiar with string.SubString method ? Using that would solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.I stil new in vb.net. I need anyone help me. Can you give me some example?

Answer (score 2):

*If* the input is always going to be xxx|xxxxxx|xxx then this is quite easily done. We can use the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Dim textToSplit As String = "1|123456|abc"

Dim text As String = textToSplit.Split(New Char() {"|"c})(1)
```

Note the use of `(1)` at the end of `.Split()`. `.Split()` returns a `String()` which results in the following output:

```
(0) 1
(1) 123456
(2) abc
```

Since you only want *123456* we can target this by appending `(1)` to the end of the `.Split` method.

Output of `text` is:

```
123456
```

Edited as OP has stated they are having problems with input "2|123456789542|ABCDSE". The format still stands as being xxx|xxxxxx|xxx so the `Split()` code will still work.

This is a screenshot of the code showing the output you are after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function:

```
Dim str() As String
str = Split(barcodeText, "|")
MsgBox("Your barcode is : " & str(1))
```

Comment: Can you give me full example because i'm still new in vb.net